# Problem with Implementation of QWidget in WPF

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, qt

I have created a Qt/C++ .dll for use in a C#/WPF project.

The Qt section code is as below:

cpluspart_global.h:

```cpp
#ifndef CPLUSPART_GLOBAL_H
#define CPLUSPART_GLOBAL_H

#include <QtCore/qglobal.h>

#if defined(CPLUSPART_LIBRARY)
#  define CPLUSPARTSHARED_EXPORT Q_DECL_EXPORT
#else
#  define CPLUSPARTSHARED_EXPORT Q_DECL_IMPORT
#endif
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void ShowSampleUI();
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int Sum(int a, int b);
#endif // CPLUSPART_GLOBAL_H
```

cpluspart.cpp:

```cpp
#include "cpluspart.h"

CPlusPart::CPlusPart()
{
}

extern "C" void ShowSampleUI()
{
    BenQ *sampleUI = new BenQ();
    sampleUI->show();
}

extern "C" int Sum(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

BenQ is an empty QDialog that is just used for tests.

Here is the implementation in C#:

```cs
[DllImport("CPlusPart.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void ShowSampleUI();

[DllImport("CPlusPart.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int Sum(int a, int b);
```

The "Sum" method works properly. However, when I want to call "ShowSampleUI", I receive the following error:

> Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFCD125286E (ucrtbase.dll) in CPlusInWPF.exe: Fatal program exit requested.

I would appreciate it if you could kindly help me with this issue.

Comment: What does `sampleUI->show()` actually do? Everything else looks fine

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This is the code inside:                                                 
''' extern "C" void ShowSampleUI()
{
    BenQ *sampleUI = new BenQ();
    sampleUI->show();
} '''

Comment: Yes what does the `show()` method do, you have not given the code for that. Please [edit] and add

Comment: You can not do Qt operations without a running Qt event loop - so where did you start the Qt eventloop?

Comment: I think that is threading issue and you should use `Dispatcher.Invoke /InvokeAsync` in WPF side

Comment: Actually the `Show()` is a native Qt function that runs the Qt event loop and shows the dialogue.